# How to call a method from class created using classloader

Tags: java, object, classloader, method-invocation

```
import java.lang.*;
public class firstclass
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{ ClassLoader classLoader = firstclass.class.getClassLoader();

    System.out.println("class A is called ...");
         try {
        Class x=classLoader.loadClass("secondclass");
         System.out.println("x has been initialized"+x);
         //Object y=x.newInstance();
         //y.disp();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();

      } 

}
}
```

Second program is

```
public class secondclass
{
public void disp()
{
System.out.println("Clss B is Called")
}
}
```

when i execute this program i get output as

```
Class A called
x has been initializedsecondclass
```

but if try to call `x.disp()`or

```
Object y=x.newInstance();
y.disp();
```

then i get the error as object not found. how to get the object of x to call disp()

Comment: I think you'll need reflection for that in oreder to work

Comment: @sudoman Keep in mind that the example is trying to call a static method, so in this case the OP needs to do it a litle bit differently. Though there is decent documentation on that

Comment: You should express your need at the beginning of the post. It's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

The most convinient way of doing this having an interface with method `disp` available to both classloaders. Secondclass can implement that interface and you can cast any instance created by the class to the interface. This can be done quite convinient with spi https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html

If you can't use an interface you need reflection.

```
    Class<?> type = classLoader.loadClass("secondclass");
    Object instance = type.getConstructor().newInstance();
    type.getMethod("disp").invoke(instance);
```